# Is using word "discriminatable" wrong?

Tags: word-usage, word-form, word-formation

Is it totally incorrect to use word **"discriminatable"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's incorrect. That's not recognized as a word in English, according to Wiktionary. You could use 'discriminable' instead.

However, it's a good guess, since it's often correct to make an adjective from a verb by adding the suffix '-able'. This case is an exception to that rule. You also correctly dropped the 'e' from the end of discriminate before adding the suffix.

Comment: So sad(because I wrote that in my test paper) but seems reasonable..

Comment: Too bad, @KYHSGeekCode. If you're ever in doubt, look it up in the dictionary first.

Comment: yep I've already done that and this question was the last hope..

Comment: Final hope, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16778 but  I hope my teacher doesn't see this question of mine..